# The odd-even topology and its basis!

Tags: general-topology

How can I show that $P=\{\{2k-1,2k\},k\in \mathbb {N}\}$ is the basis of $\mathbb N$.
Obviously we have to show that basis's orders do work.
But the problem is if I take two subsets that belong to $P$ , for example $P_1=\{1,2\}$ , $P_2=\{3,4\}$ , I get $P_1 \cap P_2=\emptyset$ , then how can I show that for every $n\in\mathbb N$ , there is $P_3\in P$  such that $n\in P_3$?

Comment: Put mathjax between $, the commands for curly brackets are \{ and \}. For subinices use _ (P_2, for example). I'll edit it for you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not used to that way of writing unfortunately

Comment: Now you can 'edit' (but changing nothing) to see how I wrote that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any *partition* $P_i, i \in I$ of a set $X$ is a base for a topology on $X$. A partition obeys:

1. $\bigcup_{i \in I} P_i = X$.
2. $\forall i \neq j: P_i \cap P_j = \emptyset$.

This translates nicely into the two conditions for definitng a base for some topology: 1. is exactly the first : every point of $X$ lies in some base element.

The other one says that whenever we have base elements $B_1,B_2$ and for any $z \in B_1 \cap B_2$, there must be an base element $B_3$ such that $z \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) or Munkres' text book.

This latter condition is easy to check, as the only way we can be in this situation of two basic sets $P_i$ and $P_j$ and a $z$ in their intersection if when $P_i=P_j$ by 2. and so we can take the required base element to be that same $P_i$!. So the other condition is fulfilled. QED.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found in your answer what i was looking for!

Comment: @Maths1999_ then you should upvote and accept it. That’s how the site works.

Comment: Yes, how to do that? I see that i still cannot upvote

Comment: @Maths1999_ up arrow above the score number on the web page.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $n$ is even, then $n\in \{n-1,n\}\in P$. If it is odd then $n\in\{n,n+1\}\in P$.

Comment: Yes it's the first order that for every n∈N there is P′∈P then n∈P′ , the second order for a topological basis was problematic for me

Answer (score 1):

For $P$ to be a basis of $\mathbb{N}$, you need to show that

1. Every natural number is contained in a basis element. Since $n\in\{n-1,n\}$ or $n\in\{n,n+1\}$, depending on whether $n$ is even or odd, this requirement is always met.
2. For every two basis elements $P_1$ and $P_2$, every element in their intersection must be contained in another basis element. If $P_1=P_2$, every element in their intersection is again contained in $P_1$. Since two different basis elements are always disjoint (and hence, every element in their intersection will have every property you can imagine, including being contained in a basis element), this requirement is also met.

Comment: Yes.That's really helped me so thanks!. The intersection of two different subsets in P is always empty, therefore i have only to take the intersection of a subset and itself,is that what happen here?

Comment: Yes, exactly (although the basis elements aren't subsets of $P$, but elements).